# Eval roslaunch substitution expression from console

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I do that?
For example

```
$ roslaunch eval '$(find my_package)/some_file'
/path/to/my/package/some_file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276466/eval-roslaunch-substitution-expression-from-console/) by [unkulunkulu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32719/unkulunkulu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik there is no entrypoint provided for that, but the following oneliner works for me (just an example):

```
python -c 'import roslaunch; print roslaunch.substitution_args.resolve_args("$(find rospy)")'
```

This prints:

```
/opt/ros/lunar/share/rospy
```

on a Lunar installation.

If you're only interested in finding the locations of packages, then `catkin_find_pkg` might be an alternative:

```
catkin_find_pkg rospy /opt/ros
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2